# JQuery .prop function not working to uncheck box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I tried many of the ideas I found here to uncheck a checkbox when a different checkbox is checked, but none are working ...

Right I now  I have :

```
$("#chkBox1").click(function () {
 if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  $('#chkBox2').prop('checked', false); }
});
```

..but no results, chkBox2 remains checked

here is a checkbox in HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="art" id="chkBox1" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" />
```

one possible difference in my code is that the checkboxes are only added to the page when a button is clicked, using href...the checkboxes are in the HTML (not created in Javascript)..but are not visible until a button is clicked..may this be part of the problem? Or am I missing something else?  Also, I am using JQuery Mobile.

Comment: Using ID's for checkboxes in JQM is probably a bad idea (using ID's in general isn't very safe in JQM due to the way page caching is handled in JQM). Most likely the correct element isn't beign selected.

Comment: You can change `$(this).is(":checked")` to `$(this).prop("checked")` or even `this.checked`. It would be more direct, but shouldn't affect the outcome.

Comment: @KevinB oh yeah.. didn't notice it was jqm - http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to refresh it after changing its' `.prop`, using `.checkboxradio('refresh')`.

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3bjmJ/)

```
// Check #chkBox2 by default
$('#chkBox2').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh')

// Uncheck #chkBox2 when #chkBox1 is checked
$('#chkBox1').on('click', function () {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('#chkBox2').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
 }
});
```

- [jQuery Mobile API reference](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh)

Comment: +1 here's the doc's as to why your answer works http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html

Comment: thanks, I came up with this answer right as you were typing it!

Comment: This is a proper jQuery Mobile way

Comment: @Gajotres You're still #1 buddy ;)

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I should have kept reading!

this seems to do the trick:

```
  $('#chkBox1').checkboxradio('refresh');
```

..but I am not exactly sure why, is this something unique to JQuery Mobile?

Comment: this should really be a comment to the answer below.. but yes if you look at the docs http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html  it shows that you need to call refresh

Comment: ps I see someone else answered this Q the same way at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="art" id="chkBox1" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" />
<input type="checkbox" name="art2" id="chkBox2" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" checked="checked" />
```

jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chkBox1").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#chkBox2').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/SwmN6/75/

Answer (score -1):

You are checking `this`, and changing `chkBox2`:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $('#chkBox2').prop('checked', false); }
```

Try this instead:

```
if ($('#chkBox2').is(":checked")) {
     $('#chkBox2').prop('checked', false); }
```

Or simply:

```
$('#chkBox2').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: this is actually referring to #chkbox1