# jquery mobile trigger click doesn't work the first time

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I have a jquery mobile form with several radio inputs whit the options "DS", "NO" and "YES". I want when I click a button it simulates a click on the "YES" option of all radio buttons.

I use this code:

```
$("#btn-all-yes").click(function(){
    $(".replay-yes").each(function(index, element){
        $(element).trigger("click");                  
        //$(element).click();       
    });
});
```

But I need to do click two times in the button to achieve the desired result. If I put the line '$(element).trigger("click")' two times it works, but I think it should work with a single call to the click event.

You can see all the code at http://jsfiddle.net/qwLPH/7/

Comment: you fiddle is working fine....??

Comment: @MohammadAdil it works on the second click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change its' status using `.prop` and then refresh it `.checkboxradio('refresh')`.

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/f67DD/)

**Update** - Uncheck other buttons

```
$("#btn-all-yes").click(function () {
 $('[data-role="controlgroup"]').find("[type=radio]").each(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('replay-yes')) {  
   $(this).prop('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");
  } else {
     $(this).prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
 });
});
```

---

**Old answer**

```
$("#btn-all-yes").click(function(){
 $(".replay-yes").each(function(index, element){
    $(element).prop('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");                  
 });
});
```

- [Reference](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh)
- [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706443/jquery-prop-function-not-working-to-uncheck-box/15706574#15706574)

Comment: thx omar, but if I have other option checked before, when I do click on "check all 'YES'" it checks the "YES" but the old option dont uncheck

Comment: @CarlosCorralCarvajal for example, if NOs' are check you want to uncheck them?

Comment: yes, I want if any other option is checked when I click the button, only the"Yes" option get checked

Comment: @CarlosCorralCarvajal i'll get you with a fix soon.

Answer (score 4):

Try to initialize the click on page load:

```
$(".replay-yes").each(function (index, element) {
    $(element).trigger("click");
    //$(element).click();       
}).click();
//-^^^^^^^----------this way
```

#### [Tryout in fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qwLPH/9/)