# jQuery Mobile Fast Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile, web-applications, user-interface, touch

Another topic on the much discussed issue of button responsiveness when web apps are used on mobile devices.

I am listening for the `touchend` event to trigger a radio button being pressed. This solves the issue of making the button more responsive, however creates another problem.

jQuery mobile applies classes such as `ui-icon-radio-on`, `ui-radio-on`, `ui-btn-hvr-a`, `ui-btn-dwn-a` when the event occurs that get left behind. This makes the button look like it is still being pressed even though the event is over. It ends up being a decent effort to juggle removing and adding all those classes to make everything look right.

My questions is - does anyone have an elegant way of adding and removing the needed classes and attributes.

or

Is there a better way of going about this that will not involve "recreating the wheel" in terms of manually dealing with the styling based on event triggers.  Would google's fast button be a better solution? (not sure how to integrate).  Is there a simpler way?

```
$(document).on('pageinit pageshow', 'div:jqmData(role="page"), div:jqmData(role="dialog")', function (event) {
if($(this).hasClass('AdminSurv') && event.type=='pageinit') {
    $(this).on( 'touchend', '.ui-radio', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        /*uncheck all radios in control group to avoid multiple checks*/
        var _control_group = $(this).parent();
        _control_group.find("input:radio:checked").attr('checked',false);

        /*check the radio*/
        $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);

        /*much juggling of classes/attributes going on here
          still looks like the buttons are being held down
          this is a very sloppy example of my initial attempt*/
        _control_group.find('label').removeClass('ui-radio-on');
        _control_group.find('label').removeAttr('data-icon');
        _control_group.find('label span span').removeClass('ui-icon-radio-on');

        $(this).find('label').removeClass('ui-radio-off');
        $(this).find('label').addClass('ui-radio-on');
        $(this).find('label').attr('data-icon','radio-on');

        $(this).find('label span span').removeClass('ui-icon-radio-off');
        $(this).find('label span span').addClass('ui-icon-radio-on');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: you should not do this hectic job. All you need to do is using `.prop('checked', false/true);` and `.checkboxradio('refresh')` check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706443/jquery-prop-function-not-working-to-uncheck-box/15706574#15706574

Comment: Perfect!  I was hoping such a solution existed.  My bad for not finding it in my hours of searching.  One small thing - using this method I do not see the input property checked="checked" getting applied when viewing the web inspector, however when I submit the form I see that indeed the POST data is there.  I do see the classes being updated though.  Strange glitch huh?  Please post the info you provided as answer so you can get credit.  And sorry again for not finding the information that was already out there.

Comment: I'm glad you got your problem solved. Ill write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many jQuery Mobile widgets accept `refresh` method, in which it is used to enhance markup of elements already existing in DOM or are inserted dynamically.

For checkbox and Radio buttons, `.checkboxradio('refresh')` combined with `.prop()` are used to enhance/modify the markup by adding/removing classes, for checked and unchecked elements dynamically.

**Check**

```
$('.selector').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

**Uncheck**

```
$('.selector').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Pauph/)**

Reference: **[Checkboxradio Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh)**