# select radiobutton with js or jqm

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, radio-button

As you can see, I have used not one, but two instructions to select the button, but none of them works. What is wrong?

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function (){     
    document.getElementById('regent1pick').checked = true;
    $('input:radio[id=regent1pick]').checked = true;
})
```

HTML :

```
<form name="COR" id="POC"   >
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
        <input type="radio" id="regent1pick" name="AKJA" onclick="regentchange()"    />
        <label class="option" for="regent1pick" style="text-align:center" >regentnik 1 </label>
    </fieldset>         
 </form>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/UdoLetO/2/edit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .prop function not working to uncheck box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706443/jquery-prop-function-not-working-to-uncheck-box)

Comment: I am not convinced of the justness of the minus one awarded. The tags used are other than mine. Radiobutton vs checkbox - even if they are one for you, they do not have to be so to others. 

I believe my question is often going to be found separately from the question you cite, which will prove usefulness of both for the future seekers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery try:

```
$('input:radio[id=regent1pick]').attr('checked','true');
```

(or simple select by id if this is option)

```
$('#regent1pick').attr('checked','true');
```

But your plain vanilla JS looks correct and should work. As an alternative you can try:

```
document.getElementById('regent1pick').setAttribute('checked', 'true');
```

**UPDATE:**

For jQuery mobile you also need refresh UI via `.checkboxradio("refresh")` method. The full command would be:

```
$('#regent1pick').attr('checked','true').checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: see the jsbin - none of them works. No idea why..
http://jsbin.com/UdoLetO/4/edit

Comment: Click on top Add Library and include jQuery

Comment: with jquery it does work:
    http://jsbin.com/UdoLetO/5/edit


but with jqm, it does not


http://jsbin.com/UdoLetO/7/edit

[strange absence of formatting of these comments, with google chrome]