# Setting button radio with JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, button, radio-button

There is a version problem of library and JQuery mobile UI
I want to add a value to a radio button group by a click button.
Took the test at : http://jsfiddle.net/BUBtL/4/

Thanks in advance

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/theme-brixky.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="field_radio_amis">
    <legend></legend>

    <label for="cat">Cat</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_animal" id="cat" class="custom" value="cat" />

    <label for="dog">Dog</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_animal" id="dog" class="custom" value="dog" />

</fieldset>
<input type="button" name="btn_go" id="btn_go" value="Click to set button radio" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn_go").click(function () {

        $('input:radio[name="radio_animal"]').filter('[value="cat"]').attr('checked', true);
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: It doesn't work with jQuery 1.6.4 for me.

Comment: When you switch to 1.10.1, then the other libraries don't work; you need updated versions of those for the newer version of jQuery. Also, you should probably use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set the "checked" property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .prop function not working to uncheck box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706443/jquery-prop-function-not-working-to-uncheck-box)

Answer (score 3):

This is a compatibility issue, you're using the wrong versions combination.

You need jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and it's corresponding CSS file to work with jQuery 1.10.1

Change `.attr` to `.prop`

```
$('input:radio[name="radio_animal"]').filter('[value="cat"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Check **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/BUBtL/1/)**

Comment: do you mean jQuery Mobile 1.4.0?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />

Answer (score 0):

oups !

See my combinaison :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
```

Comment: You have 2 jQuery files there mate. You only need 1.10.1 and not 1.9.1

Comment: Update it for you. If something doesn't work don't post it here as an answer, just update your question. This is not a thread. :)